# Hiding a div before animation starts

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm using the existing theme from the [link](http://www.scoopthemes.com/templates/Oleose/Freeze/) On a fresh loading of the page, you do see some div elements being visible before the page's animation actually starts.

Under style.css we do see that they tried to prevent that flickering before the animation starts:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

That didn't really fix the issue. Is there a way to fix that early display of div elements before the animation starts?

Update:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    width:0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    width:100px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    width:0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    width:100px;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

I see the issue happening on Chrome and mobile device.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div#tp-caption').hide('slow');
});
```

This works in safari & firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: make the divs style display:none in the HTML markup ... only display them once you are ready to do so

Comment: why not use `$().hide();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:-

```
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    width:0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    width:100px;
  }
}
```